# How to access unbound parameters in C# CommandLine Parser by gsscoder?

Tags: command-line-parser

There's a [CommandLine](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline) parser library for C# written by gsscoder. It parses command-line options in `getopt` style, i.e.:

```
myprogram --foo --bar=baz abc def ghi
```

It can also have so called “unbound” parameters, i.e freestanding positional parameters that are not bound to options; in the example above these are `abc`, `def`, and `ghi`. Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/wiki/Grammar-Details) only mentions that “the parser has its means to handle these,” but doesn't give an example. And my C# is not that sharp so I'm intimidated by the amount of source code to scan to find it out.

Could someone please give an example of how to access these unbound parameters after parsing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `ValueList[Attribute]` (see [docs on CodePlex](http://commandline.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The-Value-List-Attribute)):

> Each value not captured by an option can be included in a collection of strings derived from **System.Collections.Generic.IList**.
>
> Obviously, this attribute has no name(s) and is derived directly from **System.Attribute**.
>   *It's currently the only exception, but it's not excluded that in the future it will have similars.*

Example (from page linked above):

```
class Options
{
  // ...
  [ValueList(typeof(List<string>), MaximumElements = 3)]
  public IList<string> Items { get; set; };
  // ...
}
```

where the `ValueList`

> 1. Must be assigned to a property of type `IList<string>`.
> 2. The constructor must accept a type derived from `IList<string>` as `List<string>`.
> 3. If the `MaximumElements` property is set to a number greater than 0, the parser will fail if the limit is exceeded.
> 4. Set `MaximumElements` to 0 means that you do not accept values disassociated from options.
> 5. The default implicit setting of `MaximumElements` (-1) allows an unlimited number of values.